# Array elements in methods and returning value back to array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am working on some code for a product (no particular item) program.  Here's what I need help learning:

I need to take two array elements(numbers[4] and numbers[5]), make a method, add them together in that method, then return and store them back to array element numbers[6].

How can I create a method that can read the information already stored in the array?

Here's my code:

```
// This is an inventory program part 1 "Section 1"
public class inventory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] inventory = new String[8]; 

        inventory[0] = "hammer"; 
        inventory[1] = "shovel";
        inventory[2] = "Product#";
        inventory[3] = "Product Name";
        inventory[4] = "Units In Stock";
        inventory[5] = "Price";
        inventory[6] = "Total Value Of Product";
        inventory[7] = "Total Value of Entire Inventory";

        float[] numbers = new float[7];

        numbers[0] = 1585;// hammers in stock
        numbers[1] = 900;// shovels in stock
        numbers[2] = (float) 7.48;// hammer price
        numbers[3] = (float) 9.98;// shovel price
        numbers[4] = ( numbers[0] * numbers[2] );// total value of hammers in inventory
        numbers[5] = ( numbers[1] * numbers[3] );// total value of shovels in inventory
        numbers[6] = ( numbers[4] + numbers[5] );// total value of products in inventory

        int[] productNum = new int[2];
        productNum[0] = 5211;// hammer part #
        productNum[1] = 5212;// shovel part #

        System.out.print(numbers[6]);
    }
    public static float total(){
        return 0;
    }        
}
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: I want to start off with numbers[6] as a value of 0. Then use a method to add numbers[4] and numbers[5]. Then return the new value and store it to numbers[6].

Comment: This code definetly server your pupose but should not use like this. Array is always group of data, In your array 2 things used for quantity, 2 things for price, 2 things for total etc. so which is not good. here you can sum in your total()method passing your value number[4] and number[5] and get the sum of both numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want your total method to add the two elements then change it to:

```
public static float total(float x, float y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

and you would call this as follows

```
numbers[6] = total(numbers[4], numbers[5]);
```